# Loading XML child nodes value in variables in C#

Tags: .net, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, windows-services

I want the xml child nodes value in individual variable. The root node is 'Parent" and the main node is 'Reports'. I have written a looping statement for each main node 'Reports' and to extract the values of the child nodes.

I am able to load the xml(with values) in loop but fetches the below error while assigning the child nodes value to avariable.

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in project.exe"

### c# code

```
 public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Project.Constants.PATHNAME, "*.xml"))
            {
                XElement ReportData = XElement.Load(file);
                var Reportinfo = ReportData.Elements("Reports");
                foreach (var Reports in Reportinfo.Nodes())
                {
                    var ReportName = Reports.Document.Element("ReportName").Value;
                    var DBExecution = Reports.Document.Element("DBExecution").Value;
                    var DBName = Reports.Document.Element("DBName").Value;
                }

                var obj = new DatabaseAction("connection1");
                var result = obj.ExecuteCommandQuery("select * from sometable");

            }

        }
```

### Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parent>
<Reports name="Report1">
  <ReportName>xzy</ReportName>
  <DBExecution>Yes</DBExecution>
  <DBName>sqldb0001</DBName>
  <OutputFileName>xyz_output</OutputFileName>
  <OutputFilePath>123</OutputFilePath>
</Reports>
<Reports name="Report2">
  <ReportName>asdf</ReportName>
  <DBExecution>false</DBExecution>
  <DBName>sqldb0002231</DBName>
  <OutputFileName>xyzasdf_output</OutputFileName>
  <OutputFilePath>123333</OutputFilePath>
</Reports>
</Parent>
```

Please let me know where i go wrong? Thanks

Comment: Reports are a child of Parent and you are getting the nodes of the root.  So use Descendants : var Reportinfo = ReportData.Descendants("Reports");  Then you do not need Nodes : foreach (var Reports in Reportinfo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution. It shows how to iterate through the *Reports* fragments and get individual child elements values in a loop.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string file = @"e:\Temp\Manivannan.xml";

    string ReportName = string.Empty;
    string DBExecution = string.Empty;
    string DBName = string.Empty;

    XDocument ReportData = XDocument.Load(file);
    foreach (var Reports in ReportData.Descendants("Reports"))
    {
        ReportName = Reports.Element("ReportName").Value;
        DBExecution = Reports.Element("DBExecution").Value;
        DBName = Reports.Element("DBName").Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Yitzhak khabinsky. Thats works. Appreciate your clean  and organised coding style.